# Delete project on Google Code Hosting and make it a commercial project

Tags: google-code

I have a project hosted on Google Code Hosting server, and I would like to delete it in order to change it into a commercial project to sell.
Is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To unpublish and schedule deletion you have to go to

> My Profile > link next to "owner role" > Administer tab > Advanced
>   (sub-nav link) > "Delete Project"

As long you are the code copyright holder you should be fine.

You should note that the process for deleting a project takes some days.